# Rewriting Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

According to what I read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) correlated sub queries are not the best when it comes to performance as the sub query needs to be executed every time for each record in the main query.

Because of this reason I am trying to rewrite the following query. I tried to rewrite the query as using `INNER JOIN` only to get different results.

Can anyone help me figure out what I missed on the new query, please?
Also, I'm using MSSQL server 2008.

Original query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    table1 t
WHERE 
    t.some_Id=123
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP  1 1       
    FROM 
        table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        table3 t3 WITH(NOLOCK)     
            ON  t3.another_id = t2.another_id 
                AND t3.yet_another_id = table1.yet_another_id //correlation with table1  
        WHERE t2.t2_id = 456  AND   t3.t3_id IS NULL
)
```

New query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    table1 t
WHERE 
    t.some_Id=123
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP  1 1       
    FROM 
        table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        table3 t3 WITH(NOLOCK)     
            ON  t3.another_id = t2.another_id
        INNER JOIN table1 t1
            ON t3.yet_another_id = t1.yet_another_id
        WHERE t2.t2_id = 456  AND   t3.t3_id IS NULL
)
```

Comment: You need the correlated subquery to do what you want.  Joining back to `table1` introduces a new instance of the table in the query.  That is not what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the comment, what do you mean, wouldn't joining the table in the subquery allow it to be executed once instead of for every row in the main query? Also, what is your suggestion rather than joining the table?

Comment: First, some databases do a good job optimizing correlated subqueries -- SQL is a way of describing the results, not a procedural language.  Second, the query might get executed but only use an index lookup, which would be quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.some_Id = 123 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT TOP  1 1       
              FROM table2 t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                   table3 t3    
                   ON  t3.another_id = t2.another_id 
              WHERE t2.t2_id = 456  AND t3.t3_id IS NULL AND
                    t3.yet_another_id = table1.yet_another_id
             );
```

If you want to improve performance, consider the following indexes:

- `table1(some_id, yet_another_id)`
- `table2(t2_id, another_id)`
- `table3(another_id, yet_another_id, t3_id)`